# How to Add new row everytime data insert in datagrid using code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

Can you help me with this. I have this code that will show the output that every time user enter the code it will list down the details. I want to do this add new row into data grid from the code behind (Its the requirement). but apparently, when I add new data, it will also add the new column with the same data again (yes obviously because of my code) but I didn't know how to do it without adding the same column.

this is the code behind

```
var col = new DataGridTextColumn();
                    col.Width = 200;
                    col.Header = "Barcode";
                    col.IsReadOnly = true;
                    col.Binding = new Binding("ItemCode");
                    dgItemDisplay.Columns.Add(col);

                    var col2 = new DataGridTextColumn();
                    col2.Width = 400;
                    col2.IsReadOnly = true;
                    col2.Header = "Item Name";
                    col2.Binding = new Binding("ItemName");
                    dgItemDisplay.Columns.Add(col2);

                    var col3 = new DataGridTextColumn();
                    col3.Width = 200;
                    col3.IsReadOnly = true;
                    col3.Header = "Item Price";
                    col3.Binding = new Binding("ItemPrice");
                    dgItemDisplay.Columns.Add(col3);
```

if I didn't put this code (dgItemDisplay.Columns.Add(col3);) the data didn't appear in the data grid.

this is my data grid in .xaml

```
<DataGrid MouseLeftButtonUp="DgItemDisplay_MouseLeftButtonUp" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Width="1096" Name="dgItemDisplay" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="auto" SelectionMode="Single" CanUserAddRows="false" SelectionUnit="FullRow" />
```

[image: this is what its look like]

I'm sorry if the explanation quite messy. I don't know how to explain it :(

my code for user insert the ItemCode.

```
private void txtItemCode_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
            string itemCode = txtItemCode.Text;


            if (e.Key == Key.Return)
            {
                SimpleItem item = cashierViewModel.validateItemOnHandCode(txtItemCode.Text, 1);

                if (item != null)
                {

                    cashierViewModel.AddItemToList(item, PosWindows2.cashier.ShopId);
                    LoadData();
                    dgItemDisplay.ItemsSource = null;
                    dgItemDisplay.ItemsSource = CashierViewModel.itemDisplayList;

 DataGridTextColumn col = new DataGridTextColumn();
                        col.Width = 200;
                        col.Header = "Barcode";
                        col.IsReadOnly = true;
                        col.Binding = new Binding("ItemCode");
                        dgItemDisplay.Columns.Add(col);

                        DataGridTextColumn col2 = new DataGridTextColumn();
                        col2.Width = 400;
                        col2.IsReadOnly = true;
                        col2.Header = "Item Name";
                        col2.Binding = new Binding("ItemName");
                        dgItemDisplay.Columns.Add(col2);

                        DataGridTextColumn col3 = new DataGridTextColumn();
                        col3.Width = 200;
                        col3.IsReadOnly = true;
                        col3.Header = "Item Price";
                        col3.Binding = new Binding("ItemPrice");
                        dgItemDisplay.Columns.Add(col3);

                        spItemDisplay.Children.Add(dgItemDisplay);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Item Not Available.", "Alert", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                }
                txtItemCode.Text = null;
            }
        }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 
                CustomExceptionHandling customExceptionHandling = new CustomExceptionHandling();
                customExceptionHandling.CustomExHandling(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

when the user insert the item code in the textbox and press the keydown it will send the details of the item code in the stackpanel.

Answer (score 0):

Could you tell me if you are doing the intended result by having one of the methods below done?

A. Write the following code in the constructor (or OnApplyTemplate) and comment out the corresponding part in "txtItemCode_KeyDown".

```
var col = new DataGridTextColumn ();
...
dgItemDisplay.Columns.Add (col3);
```

B. Write a field variable such as bool isColumnAdded = false; in the class.And change inside "txtItemCode_KeyDown" as follows.

```
if (!isColumnAdded)
{
    isColumnAdded = true;
    var col = new DataGridTextColumn ();
    ...
    dgItemDisplay.Columns.Add (col3);
}
```

The DataGrid.Columns.Add method is a method to increase the column of the DataGrid on the UI.
Once the ItemCode, ItemName, ItemPrice columns are displayed, the columns will remain visible.
(I'm sorry if you understood it already.)

Comment: hi sir, thank you for your time. I've updated my question with the code. I really need help with this :(

Comment: Looking at the code, it seems that Columns.Add is called each time "txtItemCode_KeyDown" is called.Adding three columns is enough only once."Columns.Add" is a method to add a column to the DataGrid.
If you call it whenever data is added, column also increase.

Comment: yes I know but I didn't find a way to do that. do you have any idea ? because I have 3 differences column (ItemCode, ItemName, ItemPrice)

Comment: I edited the answer as it got longer.
Please take a look.